# Simulating one diff equation with a changing parameter from an ODE system

Tags: python, numerical-methods, ode, odeint

I am trying to see the evolution of a population **T** by changing one parameter in my equation, below a code a tried, but it shows an Indexerror, please take a look and contact me for any remarks, I will appreciate your help! regards

PS: I already made the ODE system simulation (with Odeint).
the dTdt is my second equation in my four coupled system.

```python
def model(T,t,d):
    dTdt = sys[1]*(a2*d - b2*sys[1]) - a1*sys[2]*sys[1]-md*sys[1]+l1*sys[0]*sys[3]
    return dTdt
# solve ODEs
t = np.linspace(0,100)
T0=500
d= 0.1
T1 = odeint(model,sys0,t,args=(d,))
d= 0.2
T2 = odeint(model,sys0,t,args=(d,))
d= 0.6
T3 = odeint(model,sys0,t,args=(d,))

# plot results
plot2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t,T1,'r-',linewidth=2,label='d=0.1')
plt.plot(t,T2,'b--',linewidth=2,label='d=0.2')
plt.plot(t,T3,'g:',linewidth=2,label='d=0.6')
```

Comment: Please do not post code as picture, use code fences and copy your code inside. It is advisable to give a minimal working example, if you do not want to publish your project code, use a similar, simplified mock-up that still shows the same problem.

Comment: What is `sys`? The ODE function returns a constant value, if it returns anything at all, as it does not use the `t` and `T` parameters.

Comment: sys is a vector of four variables including T population.

Comment: Ok, so you know that, and I had guessed this. But how is the computer to know that, it has no built-in crystal ball. Where does the function `model` get the `sys` variable from, and how do you make sure that it is the correct state for the solver-requested time `t`?

Comment: Lutz thank you for ur interest to understand my problem, i actually posted my question just to receive IDEAS, not codes, but i ended up building one that shows the results i desire, thank you again :)